# Unit test Kendo UI for Angular version 2 4 or 5

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, kendo-ui, jasmine

I'm trying to create unit tests for a Kendo UI element, I'm using Jasmine and Karma and Angular 5:

```
<kendo-arcgauge [value]="value" [scale]="scale" [color]="color" [transitions]="transitions">
    <ng-template let-value="value">
        {{ value }}%
    </ng-template>
</kendo-arcgauge>
```

The problem comes when I try to test the scale value. The scale is an object `ArcScale`

```
 {

labels?: RadialLabels;

rangeDistance?: number;

startAngle?: number;

endAngle?: number;
}
```

In this case the DOM in the HTML file looks something like this:

```
<kendo-arcgauge ng-reflect-scale="[object Object]"> ...
```

I searched the web and I can't find some way to test this code.

Comment: you want to test whether `kendo-arcgauge` component is working or not? it's actually job of  creators of `Kendo UI`. In your code, you should just take care that the component is receiving `scale` value. - 'Separation of Concern`.

Comment: any how, if you really want to test it, then write html markup for the component providing all the values, compile the template, and then check whether `value` is there in the html or not